# Unable to execute Firestore function

Tags: node.js, firebase, notifications, google-cloud-firestore, schedule

I already create server on Firebase function, Now i am creating Schedule notification on this function. But this function is called but not fire or execute. please help how to execute this time based function using node JS.

```
var date = new Date(2018, 6, 17, 10, 50);

    exports.newEvent = functions.firestore.document("Events/{event_id}").onWrite((change, context) => {

         console.log('event id', context.params.event_id);
        // console.log('Join_event id', context.params.event_id);
         const id = context.params.event_id;

         return admin.firestore().collection("Events").doc(id).get()
        .then(queryResult =>{

             const uid=queryResult.data().user;
             console.log("User id from event",uid);
             const da=queryResult.data().date;
             console.log("User id from event",da);
        const req = context.params.event_id;

    schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){

        console.log('running every 2 minute');
        console.log(id);
        return admin.firestore().collection("Events").doc(id).get()
       .then(queryResult =>{

            const uid=queryResult.data().user;
            console.log("User id from event",uid);

              return admin.firestore().collection("User_data").doc(uid).get()
               .then(snapshot2 =>
                 {
                  const tid3=snapshot2.data().token_id;
                  const useremail =snapshot2.data().user_email;
                  const username =snapshot2.data().user_firstname;


                  console.log(" User Name: ", username);
                  console.log(" User Email: ", useremail);
                  console.log(" Token_id: ",tid3);



                      const payload3 = {
                          notification:{
                              title:username,
                              body:"Event test notifiction",
                              icon: "default"
                            }
                      };
                      console.log(payload3);
                      const options4 = {
                            priority: "high",
                            timeToLive: 60 * 60 *24,
                            content_available: true,
                           };
                        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tid3, payload3,options4).then(result => {
                            return console.log('Notify when event time changed');
                        });
          });
         });

     });
     return true;
    });
     });
```

i already create demo function. its called on time and successfully print log.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the Cloud functions are limited to 60 seconds execution after that the instance of function will not execute so your cron job will not run.

Second you are reading data from firestore using admin sdk in firestore fucntion on the same node. You have data in the `change` variable. see firebase docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

Also FCM doesn't support later delivery.

For your case you need your own node server which is listening to the path you need.